# BKT transition: nature of topological transition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, topological-order, topological-phase

BKT-transition is one of the most well-known topological transition in $O(2)$ model.But I misunderstand the physical interpratation of this transition. I started from the low-temperature expansion of partition function and work in spin-wave approximation which means that I look for only single-valued solutions of the equation $\partial^2\phi=0$. I consider two-point correlation function and obtain the typical answer: correlator has the $\ln$-behavior. Then, I regularize it with IR cut-off and UV cut-off (lattice spacing $a$) and it gives the following expression for 2-point correlator:
$$G_{\text{sw}}(x,y)=\left(\frac{a}{|{\bf x}-{\bf y}|}\right)^{smth},$$
where $smth$ means the coupling constant (explicit expression doesn't matter).

Then, I allow multi-valued solutions of $\partial^2\phi=0$ which here and further I will label by $\theta$-solution and call them vortices. After lot of derivation, I obtain the well-known answer: the existence of vortices does not change the 2-point correlator but changes coupling constant. From this change, one can see BKT-transition.

But what about physical interpretation? When I consider $\theta$-solutions, I define winding number for $O(2)$. So, there is a point of view that BKT transitions just means that two vortices with different charges $+1$ and $-1$ (vortices with bigger charges are suprresed by entropy factor) in low-$T$ phase form dipoles and in high-$T$ phase this dipoles decay into free vortices.

I have found [the interesting paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2649) where authors discuss improper rotations in $O(2n)$ and show that winding number is conserved under improper rotation. Therefore, $\theta$-solution can be transformed into "anti-vortex" (see fig. 4 and fig. 5 in the paper and their captions). It seems pretty good: defect (vortex) annihilates with anti-vortex (see fig. 5) to produce smooth spin field, which is exactly spin-wave phase. But this discussion is confusing to me and finally I completely misunderstant "physical" (i.e. naive and simple) interpretation of BKT-transition.